# How to implement AMP-Consent Component flow on AMP Page?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

The newly introduced AMP-Consent Component has some really nice features, which i would adapt in order to comply with the new cookie - policy.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13716

My question is: how to implement an endpoint and how to trigger this (xhr)? I haven't found an really working solution for this till yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find two sample flows on how to use amp-consent on [ampbyexample.com](https://ampbyexample.com/#user_consent).

Comment: thank you Sebastian. The only question that remains is, how i am supposed to implement the endpoint, in the above example: "checkConsentHref": "/samples_templates/consent/getConsent".

Comment: A CORS endpoints can be specified via the `checkConsentHref` attribute. This endpoint will be queried via a POST request to determine if the consent UI specified for it needs to be shown. The response should look like this:

{
    "promptIfUnknown": boolean (true/false)
}

The response will indicate if the consent needs to be shown or not.
If it needs to be shown, the element with the id given in `promptUI` will be displayed.

Comment: @SebastianBenz so are you saying that we can now essentially implement the component on our AMP pages? Is it production ready?

Comment: Here is yesterday's blog post announcing the component: https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2018/04/18/new-tools-for-building-user-controls-in-amp-pages/. It's currently still marked as experimental, but will launch soon.

Comment: @SebastianBenz, does the amp-consent supports an the moment only one consent instance? I was strongly suggesting that the purpose of amp-consent was to enabling mutiple consents instances , as shown here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13716. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: At the moment is supports only a single instance, support for multiple consents is planned (afaik). Please chime in on the discussion on Github if you want to know more.